# Find $f\left(\frac{2020\pi}{9} + 2021 k\pi\right)$, where $k$ is an integer if, $f(x) = 4 \sin^2 (\frac{3x}{2}) - 4\cos^2 (\frac{3x}{2})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Find $f\left(\frac{2020 \pi}{9} + 2021 k \pi \right)$, where k is an integer number if $f(x) = 4 \sin^2 \left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) - 4\cos^2 \left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)$.

My approach :

\begin{align*}
    f(x) &= 4 \sin^2 \left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) - 4 \cos^2 \left(\frac{3x}{2}\right) \\
    f(x) &= -4\cos(3x) 
\end{align*}

Now,
\begin{align*}
    f\left(\frac{2020 \pi}{9} + 2021 k \pi \right) &= -4 \cos\left[ 3 \left(\frac{2020 \pi}{9} + 2021 k \pi \right)\right] \\
    & = -4 \cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{3} + k\pi\right)
\end{align*}
The answer will be $- 2$ or $2$ depending on the value of $k$. Is there a fixed answer for this question?

Also, is this the correct approach? If yes, please guide how to proceed further. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a challenge question?  Is it current?  Use of year numbers, e.g. 2021, is common in these questions.  This one is a little odd with 2020 and 2021 so it might be last year's or this year's.

Comment: Also you should finally get a numerical value.

Comment: @MathLover : $cos^2x - sin^2x = cos2x$ what's wrong..

Comment: @MathLover , i have done the correction.. sorry for that...

Comment: Yes I think $k$ being even and odd are two cases with values $2$ and $-2$.